# AdMob ads stop showing suddenly on all devices

Tags: android, google-play, admob, ads, logcat

AdMob ads in one of my apps have been showing normally for the first **1.5 days** after being published on **Google Play**. However, all of a sudden, ads **stop showing**, which occurred in all 3 devices available to me. I **did not update** the app on Google Play during this period.

Logcat in **Android Studio** shows **"Ad failed to load : 3"**, which means **ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL**. However, there are **no current issues** in my AdMob **Policy center**, and the "no fill" situation has been present for **10+ hours**.

What should I do next?

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL), `ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL` means,

> The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

This is not your problem. Sometimes there are no ads to be shown.